# How to get all keys and all values from an array?

Tags: php

I have an array

```
array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3)
```

I want to get

```
array('a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3)
```

How do I do that? Is it possible not to use each/loop ?

Comment: `foreach ($array as $key => $value) { $result[] = $key; $result[] = $value; }`

Comment: What code do you have now? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured, for the heck of it, a ridiculous one-liner(*):

```
$a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);

$result = array_combine(range(0, count($a) * 2 - 1, 2), array_keys($a)) + array_combine(range(1, count($a) * 2, 2), array_values($a));
ksort($result);

print_r($result);
```

(*) It still needs `ksort()` as a separate step.

#### Update

Based on OP's comment, I realized it could be made more succinct (*)

```
$result = explode('=', http_build_query($a, '', '='));
```

(*) Sacrificing correctness

Comment: I thought of a better way:

$a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
$b = explode('&', str_replace('=', '&', http_build_query($a)));
print_r($b);

Comment: @Jasper I'm not sure I understand the reason for the request.  http_build_query most likely uses a foreach loop to setup the variables, so now you are just adding an explode() to a function that uses foreach anyways.  You'll just be adding overhead and confusing other developers using something like this in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Use a foreach ($array as $key=>$value) then dump them into a new array.

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
 $b[] = $k;
 $b[] = $v;
}
print_r($b);
// output - Array ( [0] => a [1] => 1 [2] => b [3] => 2 [4] => c [5] => 3 )
```

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` is the recommended way but i don't know why you need it in a array function

I used `array_walk` instead of the foreach

```
<?php
$arr=array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
$new_arr = array();
array_walk($arr,function ($v,$k) use (&$new_arr) { $new_arr[]=$k;$new_arr[]=$v;});
print_r($new_arr);
```

**output**:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => 1
    [2] => b
    [3] => 2
    [4] => c
    [5] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example if you do not what to use a loop:

```
$a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
$flip = array_flip($a);

$return = array_merge(array_values($a), array_values($flip));
```

Comment: Did you test the code ?

Comment: Yes, it gives `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => a [4] => b [5] => c )`

Comment: Is that how the OP wanted as output ?

Comment: This is not interleaved.

Comment: but i want to Array ( [0] => a [1] => 1 [2] => b [3] => 2 [4] => c [5] => 3 )